# SO(n) as a manifold

Tags: manifolds, eigenfunctions

I cannot find some basic information on $SO(n)$ ($n$ general, not just 3) as a manifold: what is the geodesic distance between two matrices, what are the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Laplace-Beltrami operator. It would be good to get a recursive definition starting from $SO(2)$, where the answers are trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The article [On strain measures and the geodesic distance to $SO_n$ in the general linear group](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05868.pdf) has an introductory section on the geodesic distance, which might be helpful. In general I would look into *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces* by Sigurdur Helgason.

Comment: Thank you for the references. I am interested in SO(n) just in order to use them. I am looking for a ready reference so that I can make statements like: the geodesic distance on SO(n) is given by this formula, and these are the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues for the Laplacian on SO(n), see []. Neither the article nor the book nor its sequel mention such formulas. There are formulas in a book by Vilenkin, but they are stated in terms of matrix elements of a group representation. It is a lot of effort to figure out what exactly are these and how they are connected with laplican eigenfunctions.